# onActivityResult not being trigger from Alert Dialog FIXED

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

Im adding the ability to upload videos in addition to photos in my app. To accomplish this, now when you click the attach button `b2`instead of the image chooser loading it loads an alert dialog `showDialog()` to ask which you would like to upload (video or photo) upon selecting, it then loads the image or video selector. Problem is now when you call the method `doPositiveClick(Activity activity, int requestCode)` from the inner class onActivityResult is not being triggered and no data being returned. I feel that has something to do with it being called from the inner class `MyAlertDialogFragment` but I'm unsure how to handle it. Thank you.

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0, RESULT_PHOTO = 1, RESULT_VID = 2;


    void showDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = MyAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(
                R.string.alert_dialog_two_buttons_title);
newFragment.setTargetFragment(ChatRoomFragment.this, REQUEST_CODE);            
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

    }





  @Override
     if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && data.getData() != null) {

        Log.v("response", "Photo Selected");


                   Uri _uri = data.getData();
                  Log.v("response", "cp1/4");
```

Code is making it to this point^^^^
                      b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.picattached);

```
if (_uri != null) {
                      //User has pick an image.
                      Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                      //cursor.moveToFirst();
                      if (cursor == null){
                       uploadMsgPic = _uri.getPath();
                       Log.i("response", "cursor == null");
                       Log.i("response", "uploadMsgPic now = " + uploadMsgPic);
                       }else{
                           Log.i("response", "cursor = "+ cursor);
                       cursor.moveToFirst();
                       Log.v("response", "cp2/4");
                       //Link to the image
                       //cursor.moveToFirst();
                       final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                       Log.i("response", "imageFilePath == " + imageFilePath);
                       Log.v("response", "cp3/4");
                       uploadMsgPic = imageFilePath;
                       Log.v("response", "4/4");
                       cursor.close();
                       if (uploadMsgPic == null)
                        uploadMsgPic = _uri.getPath();
                      }
                      Log.i("response", "uploadMsgPic == " + uploadMsgPic);
                      media_attached=true;



                  }

              }
           if(requestCode == 6 && data != null && data.getData() != null){
               Uri _uri = data.getData();
              Log.v("response", "cp1/4");
              b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.picattached);
              if (_uri != null) {
                  //User has pick an image.
                  Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                  //cursor.moveToFirst();
                  if (cursor == null){
                   uploadMsgPic = _uri.getPath();
                   Log.i("response", "cursor == null");
                   Log.i("response", "uploadMsgPic now = " + uploadMsgPic);
                   }else{
                       Log.i("response", "cursor = "+ cursor);
                   cursor.moveToFirst();
                   Log.v("response", "cp2/4");
                   //Link to the image
                   //cursor.moveToFirst();
                   final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                   Log.i("response", "imageFilePath == " + imageFilePath);
                   Log.v("response", "cp3/4");
                   uploadMsgPic = imageFilePath;
                   Log.v("response", "4/4");
                   cursor.close();
                   if (uploadMsgPic == null)
                    uploadMsgPic = _uri.getPath();
                  }
                  Log.i("response", "uploadMsgPic == " + uploadMsgPic);
                  media_attached=true;

              }

          }

           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    }


//Generics:
//1. Long: Type of reference(s) passed to doInBackground()
//2. String: Type of reference passed to onProgressUpdate()
//3. STRING: Type of reference returned by doInBackground()
//Value passed to onPostExecute()





    public static void doPositiveClick(Activity activity, int requestCode) {
        Log.i("ChatRoomFragMent", "doPositive Clicked");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE);



        // Do stuff here.
        Log.i("ChatRoomFragMent", "picture selector loaded");
    }

    public void doNegativeClick() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), RESULT_VID);


        // Do stuff here.
        Log.i("FragmentAlertDialog", "Negative click!");
    }

    public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

        public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
            MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("title", title);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }


        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");
           return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    //.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setPositiveButton("Photo",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  Intent data = new Intent();

                            //((FragmentAlertDialogSupport)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                            ChatRoomFragment.doPositiveClick(getActivity(), 5);
                            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_PHOTO, data);
                         }
                        }
                    )
                    .setNegativeButton("Video",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                //((FragmentAlertDialogSupport)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                                //doNegativeClick();
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .create();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy code! How about starting out with *just* your `onActivtiyResult()` and your `AlertDialog`?

Comment: maybe you are not calling super.onActivityResult() in your Activity.onActivityResult  implementation?

Comment: sorry. i chopped it down.

Comment: Don't think will work. Correct me if I'm wrong but you have to start your Activity with startActivityForResult to receive the "answer" in onActivityResult. Just calling newInstance on Dialog will not return in where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to set your target fragment for your dialog. to do this add the line before you show the dialog:

```
newFragment.setTargetFragment(ChatRoomFragment.this, REQUEST_CODE);
```

within your showDialog method. Doing so will tell your dialog which fragment is supposed to receive the activity's result.

Also, define three constants:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0, RESULT_PHOTO = 1, RESULT_VID = 2;
```

Now, within your Dialog, you should be doing something along the lines of:

```
...setPositiveButton("Photo",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(...) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_PHOTO, data); 
        }})
.setNegativeButton(...
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_VID, data); ...
```

Then in your onActivityResult method, you need to do a check for the request code and result code pairs:

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_PHOTO) { doPositiveClick(); } ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have a question. isn't the Requeset_code not set until after the image chooser has completed? should i set the `REQUEST_CODE` in the doPositive method?

Comment: The REQUEST_CODE is the tag essentially that is attributed to the result from the dialog. Ie. when you set the REQUEST_CODE for the target, then your dialog will respond to that request with its data.

Comment: Bear with me. I've updated my question. When I add the line you gave i get an error saying that `REQUEST_CODE` cannot be resolved. So I add the constant. `public static int REQUEST_CODE = 0;` and add `REQUEST_CODE=requestCode;` to the doPositiveClick? If this is correct, it's still not working.

Comment: Ok, I expanded to my answer above to help show you all the steps you need to get the activityResult running right

Comment: THANK YOU! I am about to try this out.

Comment: Thank you again but here is my issue. The code you have me inputting into the dialog has the onActivityResult being called before the chooser is even loaded. And that's exactly whats happening accord to my Log notes. It makes to ` b2.setImageResource(R.drawable.picattached);` because the icon does change put data isnt carried over. I will update my question with current code to make sure i got it right.

Comment: FIXED!!! I've updated my question I did things a little different but your answer was spot on. Thank you!!

Comment: my rep is only 14 so I can't up vote you. but everyone here should because it IS the correct answer

Comment: You should still be able to click the green check mark to the left of my response to accept this as the answer. I'm glad I was able to help out