# onActivityResult never gets called. No obvious reason why

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I am trying to pass a String from a popup activity back to `MainActivity` but `onActivityResult` is never called. 
I have checked every common mistake, after reading many SO topics but I haven't found any solution.

My code:
In `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String phone = data.getStringExtra("result");
            addPhonesAction(phone);
        }
    }
}

public void addPhonesPopUp(View v){
     Intent phoneDialog = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPhoneDialog.class);
     startActivityForResult(phoneDialog, 1);
}
```

In AddPhoneDialog.java

```
public void okAction(View v) {
    EditText phoneText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneDialog);
    String result = phoneText.getText().toString();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    finish();
}

public void cancelAction(View v){
    finish();
}
```

Can you help me with this one?
Thanks

Edit:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gus.uniman">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AddPhoneDialog"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try by deleting the line : `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: No change. I actually added this as a possible solution. Found it on another SO question.

Comment: Is MainActivity is extending by BaseActivity (or) any other your Activity?

Comment: MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);` Try with `AddPhoneDialog.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);`.

Comment: @greenapps Still no change :/
`AddPhoneDialog.this` is implied by default anyway.

Comment: `AddPhoneDialog` extends which class? Dialog classes will not invoke onActivityResult. You better use your own Callback then.

Comment: @greenapps `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: please, show your Manifest.xml

Comment: Added it in my question

Comment: @Dinos_12345 Is it not working for both actions? okAction and cancelAction?

Comment: @Dinos_12345 You may want to check if both of your action methods are getting triggered.

Comment: It works. I'll update my question with the solution.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21486457/1741586

Comment: Hard to believe that adding a an intent for result `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` would be the solution for Activity.RESULT_OK to trigger. I´ve never used Activity.RESULT_CANCELED anywhere.

Comment: @greenapps I know it's weird, but that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark this as solved, I discovered later that I had done a stupid mistake, where I called the `okAction` when clicking "cancel" instead of doing it when clicking `ok`. I am sorry for being such a noob, I should have done a better job finding the issue before asking.
Thanks to everyone for taking the time to comment and reply

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

to

```
Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
```

Comment: I found the solution. See my question for it.

Answer (score 0):

Set proper result E.g. RESULT_OK or RESULT_CANCEL in **AddPhoneDialog**.

onActivityResult should be implemented in the class which has built-in startActivityForResult method.